# remove results from query if group is null

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the below table:

Criteria:

Do not show results for grpid if there is a `null` custuserid for all grpid

`grpid` 145 should be seen as there is a `custuserid` on the second row.

```
Custid    grpid   custuserid   date
  101       145                12/30/19
  101       145     dellf      1/1/20
  101       255     dellf      1/1/20
  201       456                1/1/20
  201       555     smithr     1/1/20
```

output:

```
Custid    grpid   custuserid   date
  101       145                12/30/19
  101       145     dellf      1/1/20
  101       255     dellf      1/1/20
  201       555     smithr     1/1/20
```

Best way to filter out these results?

I was thinking `first_value` could be used but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simpy use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.grpid = t.grpid and t1.custuserid is not null
)
```

The correlated subquery ensures that at least one record with the same `grpid` has a non-null `custuserid`. For performance, you want an index on `(grpid, custuserid)`.

You could also use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, max(custuserid) over(partition by grpid) max_custuserid 
    from mytable t
) t
where max_custuserid is not null
```

Or, you can join an aggregate query:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
    select 
        grpid, 
        max(custuserid) 
    from mytable 
    group by grpid 
    having max(custuserid) is not null
) x on x.grpid = t.grpid
```

Which option performs best would depend on your dataset (size, cardinality, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Try below query

```
select * from temp1 where grpid not in (select grpid from temp1 group by grpid having count(custorid)=0)
```